# UI Change in Swing application across platforms

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, absolutelayout

My Swing Application's GUI is built using `Window Builder Pro` GUI editor. Layouts used are `MigLayout` and `AbsoluteLayout`. Application is developed using `Windows` Machine, So UI is well aligned and neat in `Windows`, but when I run the same application in `Mac OS X`, Application's `Frame` couldn't accommodate the components inside its `bounds`. I mean, size of `Components` inside the frame changes across platforms. When I give extra space(Increased frame bounds), it looks nice in `Mac` but weird in `Windows`. Is there any way to have `Frame` or `Panel` to grow with respect to its contents or `Components`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the absolute layout. Layout managers are used precisely to avoid the kind of problems that you're facing.

Comment: +1, Exactly, seems like you just stole my answer, hehe just kidding    :-) Regards

Comment: How about `MigLayout`? I have used it everywhere. Are they similar to `Absolute Layout`?

Comment: If it suits your needs, go with it. It's a well-known layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used `AbsoluteLayout` because none of the existing layout managers suited your needs,

> Have a look at [Creating a Custom Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html) and use one instead of AbsoluteLayout.(Before that make sure none of the present layout managers suit your need)

Comment: - I dont' like the color of my car; - Here's a brief guide on how to build your own car paint factory so you can create the color you want!

Comment: @DenisTulskiy I specified, Do this only in case you dont want to use ANY OF THE EXISTING COLOUR for your car :) Do you have any other option??